# Load Model relations from a Observer method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

How can i load a relation from a model in an Observer?
When i try to load the relation in the `created` method using `$inport->load('items')` it returns an empty array.
This is the relation defined in my `Inport` model:

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(InportItem::class);
}
```

Observer Method

```
public function created(Inport $inport)
{
    dd($inport->load('items'));
}
```

`Inport` table

```
id
name
```

`inport_items` table

```
id
inport_id
number
```

Comment: whats your laravel version?

Comment: @user15070659 My version is 8.27, i'll update the title.

Comment: can you share some more information? For example, your primary ID and foreign ID. it is important.

Comment: @r89human `inport_items` table is connected using the foreign key `inport_id` from the `id` of the `inport` table

Answer (score 1):

you need to try

```
dd( $inport->items );
```

and your items() method should be like.

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(InportItem::class, 'inport_id', 'id'); // where inport_id is your foreign key and id is your primary key in inport_items table
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm trying to `Load` the relation is because the observer doesn't see the relation of the model. `dd( $inport->items )` returns an empty array. Yes, i have data in my database. Yes, `dd( $inport->items )` is working outside the `observer ` class and returns the desired data.

Answer (score 1):

The observer doesn't see the relation, because it hasn't been created yet.

The `hasMany` relationship means that the `InportItem` class stores the id of your `Inport` model, and it can only store the id of your `Inport` model *after* it is created.

Your options:

- Attempt using the [`afterCommit` property](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers-and-database-transactions) on your observer (I'm not sure if this will work)
- Use an observer for the `created` event on your `InportItem` model, instead of your `Inport` model (you may want to add a `belongsTo` on your `InportItem` linking it to `Inport`)

Answer (score 1):

The Inport observer method is triggered as soon as you call `$inport->save()` or `Inport::create([])`

At this point, the inportItems have not been created yet. You probably do something like this on the next line: `$inport->inportItems()->create([...])`

So you need to:

1. Create an InportObserver class with `public $afterCommit = true`
2. Wrap your `$inport->save()` and your `$inport->inportItems()->create([])` calls inside a DB::transaction. That way the parent observer method will be triggered AFTER the children have been created.